# Can anyone explain eager_few_shot_od_training_tflite.ipynb code

Tags: image, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to understand example code provided by tensorflow team in github link [eager_few_shot_od_training_tflite.ipynb](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/eager_few_shot_od_training_tflite.ipynb). I am able to understand most of the code except below few lines of code.

1. Not sure why we are creating `fake_box_predictor` variable and creating `fake_model`?
2. Why can't we restore checkpoint on `detection_model` directly instead of creating `fake_model`?
3. Also I do not understand comments above code "We will restore the box regression head but initialize the classification head from scratch".

Can anyone explain in detail what below code is doing (and comments provided above this code mean)?

```
# Set up object-based checkpoint restore --- SSD has two prediction
# `heads` --- one for classification, the other for box regression.  We will
# restore the box regression head but initialize the classification head
# from scratch (we show the omission below by commenting out the line that
# we would add if we wanted to restore both heads)
fake_box_predictor = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(
    _base_tower_layers_for_heads=detection_model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads,
    # _prediction_heads=detection_model._box_predictor._prediction_heads,
    #    (i.e., the classification head that we *will not* restore)
    _box_prediction_head=detection_model._box_predictor._box_prediction_head,
    )
fake_model = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(
          _feature_extractor=detection_model._feature_extractor,
          _box_predictor=fake_box_predictor)
ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=fake_model)
ckpt.restore(checkpoint_path).expect_partial()
```

Answer (score 1):

The details and documentations are extremely sparse on this topic. My understanding on this is,

**2.** Here weights of pretrained checkpoint are loaded for some of the layers for transfer learning and rest are initialized from scratch to learn the new class. The detection model is built from given config. If the [checkpoint](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint) was restored on `detection_model` then it will detect the classes from `COCO` dataset since [TF2 detections model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md) pretrained models are trained on COCO dataset.

**3.** The goal is to classify a new class of images. This is associated with class prediction layers. So these layers should be initialized from scratch and the rest feature extraction layers, bounding box regression layers are restored from checkpoint so model can take advantage of these pretrained weights. This will help the model converge faster as well as detect the new desired classes.

**1.** This is the process for loading partial model. The `base_tower_layers_for_heads` [contains the earlier layers](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/1180f37efac174765973a5416efc88324903ac9e/research/object_detection/predictors/convolutional_keras_box_predictor.py#L380) before the class prediction and box regression heads.

`_box_prediction_head` predicts the bounding boxes. If `_prediction_heads=detection_model._box_predictor._prediction_heads` was used the it should restore both classification and regression heads as it [contains both](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/1180f37efac174765973a5416efc88324903ac9e/research/object_detection/predictors/convolutional_keras_box_predictor.py#L121) `box_prediction_heads` and `class_prediction_heads`.

`detection_model._feature_extractor` is [likely the initial layers containing](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/0537226c75d542225553ca2a7ae3b88fb75b0d7a/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py#L1314) classification network such as Resnet, Mobilenet + FPN for feature extraction.

`fake_model` connects bbox regression head + its earlier layers with the base feature extraction layers such as mobilenet in a computation graph. `vars(fake_model)` will contain `_box_predictor` and `_feature_extractor`.

The desired weights are then restored from pretrained checkpoint and `expect_partial()` is used to [silence warning](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint#restore) about unused part of checkpoint.

Tensorflow advanced computer vision course on coursera has more details on this as well as overall tensorflow object detection structure and code. Corrections for any mistakes is welcome.